# Async Problems with jQuery & Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm going round in circles and can't seem to figure out a solution from the resources currently available here on Stack or Google. There's got to be something obvious that I'm missing, perhaps you might be able to help?

**Story summary:**

- A javascript function launches when clicked and creates a new contact in our database.
- Additional functions are then called upon successful creation to toggle some settings where necessary, dependant on a few checkboxes.
- Calls are currently being made asynchronously, resulting in only the last function call to successfully update the contact.
- I can't, for the life of me, get the call to work one after the other instead.
- Each call returns a JsonResult upon successful completion, if that helps at all (needed for other areas of the application.

**Code currently looks like:**

`function CreateClicked(){
  Contact.Create(**bunch of params**, function(data){
    if(data.success) {
          togglePrimary(data.newId);
          toggleBilling(data.newId);
          toggleTechnical(data.newId);
          toggleBalance(data.newId);
          toggleSecurity(data.newId);
          toggleMarketing(data.newId);
          Modal.Load(**loads a modal view**);
    }
  }
}`

The toggle functions then look like:

`function togglePrimary(id) {
  if ($("#contact_admin_primaryrole").prop('checked')) 
     {Contact.TogglePrimaryRole(id);}
}`

Which calls a controller function that looks like this:

`public JsonResult TogglePrimaryRole(int contactId){
try{
var c = new Contact(contactId);
c.IsPrimaryContact = !c.IsPrimaryContact;
c.Update(AuthenticatedUser.Username, !c.IsPrimaryContact);
return Json(JSONResponseFactory.SuccessResponse("Contact updated successfully"));
}
catch (Exception ex){
return Json(JSONResponseFactory.ErrorResponse(ex.Message));
}
}`

How should I go about setting this up so that each toggle function doesn't start until the previous one has finished and returned a Json response, regardless of success?

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Dez

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery promises should help:

```
togglePrimary(data.newId).then(toggleBilling(data.newId)).then(toggleTechnical(data.newId)
```

etc.

This will run the next function only if the last one was a success. If you want to call the function irrelevent of the outcome then use always() instead of then()

```
togglePrimary(data.newId).always(toggleBilling(data.newId)).always(toggleTechnical(data.newId)
```

This will require jquery 1.6 or higher to be referenced. To reference from the CDN add the following

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Trying both ways now executes the first function correctly, but then I get the following error on the rest of them: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'always' of undefined"

Comment: Do you have Jquery referenced? Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Yep, jQuery is referenced in the document, but really doesn't seem to like either this() or always() methods. :/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't seem to get anywhere with promises, or javascript function chaining with callbacks... so I turned the values of each status into an array of strings and parsed it within the controller instead!

Thanks for helping :)